# C++ program returns -1073741515 when is called from the Java Tomcat Servlet

Tags: java, c++, opencv, tomcat, servlets

I have a C++ application which deals with the image processing (by OpenCV 2.4.10). When I call this program from the command line or from another local Java application with the following code snippet:

```java
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(_IMG_PROC_ENGINE_PATH, imgPath);
pb.redirectError();
Process p = pb.start();
exitCode = p.waitFor();
```

everything is working and the CPP-application returns the correct outcome.

But when I call the same CPP-program on the same PC with absolutely the same user account from ***Java Tomcat Servlet***, I get an error return code ***-1073741515*** from the CPP. After some searching, I discovered that this code error occurs when there is a problem with an external library loading. And it's true if I remove the OpenCV libraries usage from my C++ program, everything is OK.

Why, when I execute the program locally from the command line or from another local Java application, everything is OK, but when I call the same C++ EXE from the ***Java Servlet***, I get an error of library loading? How can I fix the issue?

P.S. There is no antivirus or any other security software (e.g. Internet Security, EMET, etc.) on the PC, which can interrupt the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the environment variables are somehow different when running in a Tomcat Servlet. That can explain why you program cannot load runtime library.

I would try to copy necessary OpenCV runtime library files to the same directory as the C++ executable.

Comment: Great! It works. Firstly, I tried to add these libs to the server IntelliJ IDEA project structure like we do it with JARs, but now I see, it's even simpler. Thank you so much, Meng Wang!